# what is the best way to get some data from web page which is readings from sensor nodeMCU+EMP280 to an android application

Tags: android

so this is the web page and im totally new in Android development
so what should i start with if i need to get these readings in my application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1xs3.jpg)

the application iam creating for simply viewing the readings that is taken by the BME280 sensor

Comment: Please post the source of the html webpage you got. Then ask what you want to parse from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing this data through your device to the Firebase Realtime Database. Then connect your app to same database and fetch the data from there.